# Binding to Jquery Nicescroll events. Which events are available?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-plugins, nicescroll

I'm using [Nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) and want to bind to a scroll event of the div the nicescroll-plugin is defined on.

Somehting like:

```
$("#sec_menu").niceScroll();  
$("#sec_menu").scroll(function(e){   //do stuff here });
```

However the above doesn't work. 
Which event (perhaps a custom event defined by nicescroll)  can I bind to that is fired on scrolling? I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Thanks

Comment: nevermind. It worked on a retry somehow.

Answer (score 9):

You can  use the custom event  only  :

```
  $("#id").niceScroll().scrollstart(function(info){
      //do something here 
  })
  // or
  $("#id").niceScroll().scrollend(function(info){
      //do something here 
  })
```

Comment: What version are you using? For me `scroll()` works just fine.

Comment: This solution worked for me with using `jquery.nicescroll 3.5.0`.

Comment: `.scroll()` is jquery event.